# Flash Builder debugger error : Flash builder failed to connect to running application

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

I am trying a simple code for event handling. I applied break point on a line of action script code of event. I want to see the debug window to check which event is generated. It does not show me any error but whenever i click the debug button i get the following problem

> The Flash Builder debugger failed to connect to the running application.
> Ensure that:
>
> 1. For in-browser applications, you are running the debugger version of Flash Player.
> 2. For network debugging on a mobile device, you have a reliable network connection to the device, and port 7935 is open on your machine's firewall.

My project runs correctly in browser showing the desired output but it shows me launching failed dialog with above error. Please help

Comment: Did you ensure the things the error message told you to ensure?

Comment: Is in-browser internet explorer? I had debugger version of flash player installed for the internet explorer but i removed it, still i get this error. i didn't understand the 2nd thing told in the error message

Comment: Yes in-browser is Internet explorer. The other is of you are running on a mobile device (iPhone/android). Why did you remove the debugging version of flash player if you are trying to debug?

Comment: :P I thought the debugger version is only for internet explorer. My default browser is Firefox. It shows me the output on Firefox but prompts me to install the latest version. Also the first thing listed in the error message is about the debugger version.

Comment: I could not run the project on internet explorer bcoz it gives me some IE script error which i could not solve. so i changed the browser.. :P :D

Comment: There are two debugging players: one for ie and one for everything else. http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: Hey i installed debugger version for other browsers.Now it doesnt prompt me about the flash player but the debugger window is blank. i cannot see which event is generated

Answer (score 5):

One other thing you can try which worked for me when the above didn't - in Flex Compiler in Properties for the project, untick Generate HTML wrapper file, apply that, then tick it again and apply again.  Seems to clean/reset the project in some way, which 'clean project' doesn't.

Comment: It started working for me after manually deleting the bin-debug folder. Project clean wasn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try to shutdown "adl.exe" in taskmanager, It seens the old adl.exe occupied port 7935 that flashplayer can't creat new one.

That's how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It happens many a time, but you can solve it in 4 ways
1) Clean the project and try.
2) Close flex builder and reopen it. try it, If that doesn't work than go for 3 option
3) Change your workspace and import that project in it or best is create new one and make the changes in it, Sometimes the workspace get corrupted and so it happens...
4) If above 3 option that doesn't work than reinstall your Flex builder, make sure that you uninstall flex builder properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly that symptom.  Blank browser window, a freeze at 57% for 2 minutes and the same error message.

The problem was an error in my javascript.  As usual, it just silently aborts whatever it is doing.  As a result, the SWF was never started and the debugger failed to connect to the running program.

So, if the browser window remains blank it is probably a javascript error.  Display the javascript console to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this issue what I had to do is re-install the adobe flash debugger version for firefox and Flash could successfully run in debug mode

**Reason for the error** : The firefox updates the flash builder version which for some reason doesn't work with the Adobe Flash Builder 4.6

You can follow below steps and get the flash application run in the debugger mode :

1) Go to https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

2) Download : `[Download the Flash Player content debugger for Firefox - NPAPI][1]`

3) Install the downloaded executable and install it over whatever version of Adobe Flash 
       builder that you have .

4) Restart the Flash Builder and run the application in debugger mode and check if it 
       works.